# MeshRenderer has wrong bounds when rotated

Tags: unity-game-engine

When I try to get the bounds of my models (created in Blender) and show them in Inspector:

[image]

As you can see the bounds are correct when the objects are not rotated. But when they are (left-most object) bounds start getting totally wrong.

Here is a script that shows / gets the bounds:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GetBounds : MonoBehaviour
{
    public MeshRenderer mesh_renderer = null;

    public bool show_bounds = false;

    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        if (!show_bounds) return;

        Gizmos.DrawWireCube(mesh_renderer.bounds.center, mesh_renderer.bounds.size);
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(mesh_renderer.bounds.center, 0.3f);
    }
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Hopefully this answers your question! https://answers.unity.com/questions/297453/finding-locations-of-vertices-on-a-mesh.html?childToView=297542#answer-297542

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In [this thread](https://answers.unity.com/questions/297453/finding-locations-of-vertices-on-a-mesh.html?childToView=297542#answer-297542) I have come across this image which explains it pretty much

[image]

Unity dos not recalculate the [`Mesh.bounds`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh-bounds.html) all the time except when you add a mesh for the first time or "manually" invoke [`Mesh.RecalculateBounds`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.RecalculateBounds.html).

It then uses this local space `Mesh.bounds` in order to calculate the translated, scaled and rotated `Renderer.bounds` in global space based on the `Mesh.bounds`. This way it always has to iterate a fixed amount of 8 vertices of the bounding box.

There was also a solution provided if you want to get the exact bounds calculated directly from the vertices. I adopted and cleaned it up a bit

```c#
public class GetBounds : MonoBehaviour
{
    public MeshRenderer mesh_renderer;
    public bool show_bounds;

    public MeshFilter meshFilter;
    public Mesh mesh;

    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        if (!mesh_renderer) return;
        if (!show_bounds) return;

        if (!meshFilter) meshFilter = mesh_renderer.GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
        if (!meshFilter) return;

        if (!mesh) mesh = meshFilter.mesh;
        if (!mesh) return;

        var vertices = mesh.vertices;
        if (vertices.Length <= 0) return;

        // TransformPoint converts the local mesh vertice dependent on the transform
        // position, scale and orientation into a global position
        var min = transform.TransformPoint(vertices[0]);
        var max = min;
    
        // Iterate through all vertices
        // except first one
        for (var i = 1; i < vertices.Length; i++)
        {
            var V = transform.TransformPoint(vertices[i]);

            // Go through X,Y and Z of the Vector3
            for (var n = 0; n < 3; n++)
            {
                max = Vector3.Max(V, max);
                min = Vector3.Min(V, min);
            }
        }

        var bounds = new Bounds();
        bounds.SetMinMax(min, max);

        // ust to compare it to the original bounds
        Gizmos.DrawWireCube(mesh_renderer.bounds.center, mesh_renderer.bounds.size);
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(mesh_renderer.bounds.center, 0.3f);

        Gizmos.color = Color.green;
        Gizmos.DrawWireCube(bounds.center, bounds.size);
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(bounds.center, 0.3f);
    }
}
```

Result:

- In WHITE: The `MeshRenderer.bounds`
- In GREEN: The "correct" calculated vertex bounds

[image]

Comment: In one of the last lines, there is a small typo: "Gizmos.DrawWireCube(bounds.center, B.size);" should be "Gizmos.DrawWireCube(bounds.center, bounds.size);"

Comment: Mr @derHugo, following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65477152/get-the-graphic-size-of-a-gameobject-challenge-skinnedmeshrenderer-bounds-and-s) topic I came across your answer. Do you know if the default white box from the unity's scene is calculated by unity or its part of the mesh? This does not change with the gameObject rotation. However I got problems when its not aligned to the gamobject's axis. Thanks for your comments

Comment: @rustyBucketBay very late response, I'm so sorry ^^ the white box was the `Renderer.bounds` which is always world aligned and is a bounding box around the scaled, rotated, translated `Mesh.bounds` of the object. The `Mesh.bounds` is always in **local** space while the `Renderer.bounds` is always in **world** space. If you need a box aligned with the objects axis you can use the `Mesh.bounds` and then convert its 8 edges into world space via `transform.TransformPoint` .. it won't work for `Bounds` itself though as these are always axis aligned