# Rotating and positioning a row of gameobjects without gaps

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, position, gameobject

I have a prefab of a house with a bit of road attached, like so:

[image: 3D model of a house, with a strip of road in front of it]

I want to arrange these side-by-side to create a street, but I also want to have them at a slight angle so that the road seems to head off into the distance. Something more like this:

[image: Same 3D model, now with the road heading off to the upper-right of the screen]

I've been able to place them and rotate them, but I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out the positioning. I'm guessing there's some maths trick I'm not applying or something.

This is my code so far:

```
        int houseCount = 0;
        float offsetX = 0;
        float offsetZ = 0;
        while (houseCount < 30)
        {
            GameObject house = GameObject.Instantiate(housePrefab);
            house.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0,-20f,0), Space.Self);
            house.transform.position = new Vector3(offsetX, 0, offsetZ);

            // Calculate offset for next house
            HouseUnit unit = house.GetComponent<HouseUnit>();
            MeshRenderer renderer = unit.GetHouseBase().GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
            Vector3 size = renderer.bounds.size;
            offsetX += size.x;
            offsetZ += size.z / 2f;

            Debug.Log(size);
            houseCount++;
        }
```

`unit.GetHouseBase()` returns the road segment, which is a simple plane. I figured that was the most logical bit to base the positioning on since it's a) the widest part, and b) the bit I need to connect up.

Running this gives the following result:

[image: A row of the above house model, with a gap between each road segment]

They're not lining up too badly, but I can't figure out how to close that gap. Has anyone got any suggestions, or resources they can point me at? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [MeshRenderer has wrong bounds when rotated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57711849/meshrenderer-has-wrong-bounds-when-rotated)

As a short summary:

- Unity takes Mesh.bounds which are in local space (unscaled, unrotated, untranslated)
- Unity then wraps this bounds within the Renderer.bounds
- Since Bounce are always world axis aligned the Renderer.bounds grows when rotating the object in order to fit the now rotated mesh bounds within

Just re-posting the image for better illustration

[image]

---

So what I would do is

1. Have a common parent object
2. Do all house placements while parent object is **not rotated**

   => Can rely on `Renderer.bounds` to be accurate
3. Then in the end rotate the parent according to your needs

   => and all children (houses) automatically along with it
4. [optional] If you then really really do not want that parent object there for whatever reason, simply once you are done un-parent all the houses maintaining their current positions and rotations and destroy the parent

something like e.g.

```
// either already have that common parent or create one now
var parent = new GameObject().transform;

// if using previously existing parent store original position and rotation
var position = parent.position;
var rotation = parent.rotation;

// ensure not rotated
parent.position = Vector3.zero;
parent.rotation = Quaternion.identity;

// span houses into parent
var offsetX = 0f;
for(var houseCount = 0; houseCount < 30; houseCount++)
{
    var house = Instantiate(housePrefab, parent, Vector3.right * offsetX, Quaternion.identity);

    // Calculate offset for next house
    var size = house.GetComponentInChildren<Renderer>().bounds.size;
    offsetX += size.x;
}

parent.position = position;
// either reapply previous rotation (if already was rotated)
parent.rotation = rotation;
// or rotate now to your desired 20°
parent.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, -20f, 0);


// [optional] as said if you then d not want the parent anymore you could also add
while(parent.childCount > 0)
{
    var child = parent.GetChild(0);
    child.SetParent(parent.parent, true);
}
Destroy(parent.gameObject);
```

Comment: Oh, this is wonderful! Especially as I was going to have to pop groups of children into parents anyway so I could make the road turn corners. Now I've run into another problem with that bit, but that's going to be a new question entirely. But the lining them up in a straight line works beautifully following your suggestions. Thank you! :D

Answer (score 0):

`renderer.bounds` is the bounding box in world space, so if you rotate the renderer, the bounds changes too. You can try `renderer.localBounds` or `Mesh.bounds`, these properties return the bounding box in local space. But please notice they are variable and usually calculated by all the vertex, that means they are not guaranteed to be accurate. If you still find gaps, you can manually measure the width of the road with the built-in cube, its width is 1.