# Rotating and positioning gameobjects in a zig-zag pattern

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, position, gameobject

This is a follow-on from the question I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76268046/rotating-and-positioning-a-row-of-gameobjects-without-gaps), but it's potentially complicated enough that I felt it deserved its own question.

Thanks to the advice of derHugo I have a long straight street of houses with a road in front of them. Looks lovely. However, I ultimately need the road to have corners, creating a zigzag pattern like this:

[image: An image showing the road heading first to the upper right of the screen, then turning to head to the upper left, then turning again to head to the upper right]

I tried simply alternating the direction that I rotated the different segments, which got me the correct directions but not the correct positioning - the segments going right ascend across the screen while the segments going left descend.

[image: Image showing the behaviour just described]

I suspect this is happening because the origin of all those road segments is still (0,0,0), but I'm not sure how to fix it. Offset mathematics is clearly not my strong suit!

Anyway, this is the code I'm working with at the moment:

```
this.housePrefab = housePrefab;

int stretchCount = 0; // A stretch is the span between two turns
int houseCount = 0;
float offsetX = 0;
bool goingRight = true;
Transform parent = new GameObject().transform;

while (houseCount < 30)
{
    // Add house to the current stretch
    GameObject house = GameObject.Instantiate(housePrefab, Vector3.right * offsetX, Quaternion.identity, parent);

    // Calculate offset for next house
    HouseUnit unit = house.GetComponent<HouseUnit>();
    MeshRenderer renderer = unit.GetHouseBase().GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
    Vector3 size = renderer.bounds.size;
    offsetX += size.x;

    // Decide if we're finished with the current stretch
    stretchCount++;
    if (stretchCount >= 2)
    {
        int dieRoll = Random.Range(0, 100);
        if (dieRoll >= 50)
        {
            // Rotate current stretch
            if (goingRight)
            {
                parent.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, -45f, 0);
            }
            else
            {
                parent.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 45f, 0);
            }
            goingRight = !goingRight;

            // Start a new stretch
            stretchCount = 0;
        }
    }

    // If we're starting a new stretch, create a new parent to hold it
    if (stretchCount == 0)
    {
        parent = new GameObject().transform;
        parent.position = Vector3.zero;
        parent.rotation = Quaternion.identity;
    }

    houseCount++;
}
```

How do I go about lifting those left turns into their proper place? Ideally they should overlap at the turns so that the road looks properly connected, but if I need to backfill the corners for the sake of keeping the maths simple I'm willing to do that too.

Comment: surely they need to be at 45 degree angles..

Comment: @BugFinder Fair point. At the very least, it might make the maths easier. I've updated the code and image accordingly. It doesn't fix the problem though - just changes the angle between the two "arms".