# how can I convert from local scale to world scale?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to set the size of a particle emission module to be the same size as the parent object that it is attached to. Problem is both of their scales are local, both being (1, 1, 1) but being different sizes. The code goes as follows so far:

```
scale = x.transform.localScale (have tried lossyScale but doesnt make a diff)
var shape = particleSystem.shape
shape.scale = scale`
```

Comment: `lossyScale` would be the world space scale (approximation) ... what do you mean by `scales are local, both being (1, 1, 1) but being different sizes.` ? Are you sure their `transform.lossyScale` is different or is it just that the object's visuals (mesh) simply has it's own scaling already? (In that case rather go by e.g `GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds.size`)

Comment: @derHugo honestly not sure, I have debugged pretty much every kind of scale that I can find and its always outputting (1, 1, 1) for both objects. In the inspector the scale for both objects is (1,1,1) which is the problem really as I the two objects are not the same size but their scales are. changing ones scale to be equal to the other actually does nothing.

Comment: As said this means their scales are indeed the same. It is rather the underlying meshes that have a different scale in itself already and you will have to go though the `bounds` instead which will be the actual visible dimensions of the object

Comment: Yeah bounds worked mate thanks a bunch :) did bounds.size of the renderer

Answer (score 0):

If as you say both sizes are `1,1,1` and you also noted no difference in using `localScale` or `lossyScale` - which confirms that they are indeed `1,1,1` through the entire hierarchy - it means the object has a **mesh** which itself brings its own scaling and dimensions.

Instead of the scale you could rather go through e.g.

```
var shape = particleSystem.shape
shape.scale = x.GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds.size;
```

which would use the [`Renderer.bounds`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-bounds.html), the world aligned bounding with the actual dimensions of your mesh with applied transforms.

note that in general `Renderer.bounds` is an approximation and might not always be super precise - see e.g. [MeshRenderer has wrong bounds when rotated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57711849/meshrenderer-has-wrong-bounds-when-rotated) - but for most cases it is enough