# Aligning one game object to another for base building system considering different rotations based on raycast hit

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, game-development

I am creating base building system similiar to Valheim's one, but I have problems with aligning objects towards themselves. I want to be able to place object with different rotation at point my camera is looking and make them stick to other objects, like in classic base building system.

I tried to determine the distance I need to move the object from the raycast hit point based on mesh renderer bounds size like below:

`visualization.transform.postion = currentHit.point + Vector3.Scale(visualization.Bounds.extents, currentHit.normal.normalized);`

This works only for right and straight angles, and becomes a problem when there are different rotations:
[image]
[image]

Is there any way to know the distance based on renderer/collider size and object rotation, without using bounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with the `Bounds` in general is they are world aligned (see e.g. [MeshRenderer has wrong bounds when rotated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57711849/meshrenderer-has-wrong-bounds-when-rotated))

If you have Colliders you could use [`Physics.CalculatePenetration`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.ComputePenetration.html)

> Translating the first collider by direction * distance will **separate** the colliders apart if the function returned `true`. Otherwise, direction and distance are not defined.

That means you would first check if the blocks overlap at all e.g. using `OnCollisionEnter` and can then use the `Physics.CalculatePenetration` to separate the blocks and male the one you move "snap" outside of the one it collided with.

If they are not overlapping then yes I would probably first use a `BoxCast` and assume you would move the object to a position where it definitely overlaps the hit and then separate again.

If it needs to work for arbitrary meshes it will get complex as the `CalculatePenetration` requires at least one convex collider.

---

If that's the case though then you can also use kinematic `Rigidbody` and do a [`Rigidbody.SweepTest`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.SweepTest.html)

Comment: Thank you for hints, this doesn't solve my problem, but it helped me to find proper solution. Also i didn't know about this function, it seems very useful :)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with similiar problem I managed to achieve this as wanted. This may not be the best way to do this, but it is working as intended.

I used normal from currentHit to cast another ray toward placeable element, then my result is raycast hit on it's surface, then i take distance between placeable element's pivot and surface hit, multiplying currentHit normal by this distance make objects do not intersect.